# Drawing circles on top of a vector field drawn using VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, vector, vector-calculus

I am using the command

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

to plot the vector field $\vec{V}=y\hat{i}-x\hat{j}$. On top of this, I need to draw circles of radii $1,2,3...$, etc. I am no expert in Mathematica. Need some help in doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Show[{VectorPlot[{{y, -x}}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}], 
Graphics[Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 1, 5}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}}, {x, -4.1, 4.1}, {y, -4.1, 4.1}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}}, 
 StreamStyle -> Black, StreamColorFunction -> None, 
 StreamScale -> None, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but note that this only works because the circles are the streamlines of the vector plot.  If for some reason you needed circles superimposed on a different vector field, you'd have to use another option.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)
```

Use the option [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html) (or [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html))

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
 Prolog -> ({AbsoluteThickness[0.7], Gray,
    Circle[{0, 0}, #] & /@ Range[5]})]
```

[image]